# Adding data into specific column Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, graph, tkintertable

I need to make a graph based on created table (user enters the vertex name, X and Y coordinates, distance column remains empty at this stage). After the data is added into table I need minimal distance to each of the vertexes be calculated and inserted into distance column. This is the code I have:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

# Creating table
def create_table():
    global table
    table = ttk.Treeview(window)
    # Creating columns
    table["columns"] = ("name", "x_coord", "y_coord", "distance")
    table.column("#0", width=100, minwidth=100)
    table.column("name", width=100, minwidth=100)
    table.column("x_coord", width=100, minwidth=100)
    table.column("y_coord", width=100, minwidth=100)
    table.column("distance", width=100, minwidth=100)
    table.heading("#0", text="Vertex")
    table.heading("name", text="Vertex name")
    table.heading("x_coord", text="X cord")
    table.heading("y_coord", text="Y cord")
    table.heading("distance", text="Min distance")
    # Отображение таблицы
    table.pack()


def add_data():
    name = entry_name.get()
    x_coord = entry_x_coord.get()
    y_coord = entry_y_coord.get()

    table.insert("", "end", text=str(len(table.get_children()) + 1), values=(name, x_coord, y_coord, int(len(table.get_children()) + 1), ""))

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x400")

# create_table()

label_name = Label(window, text="Vertex name:")
label_name.pack()

entry_name = Entry(window)
entry_name.pack()

label_x_coord = Label(window, text="X cord:")
label_x_coord.pack()

entry_x_coord = Entry(window)
entry_x_coord.pack()

label_y_coord = Label(window, text="Y cord:")
label_y_coord.pack()

entry_y_coord = Entry(window)
entry_y_coord.pack()

button_add = Button(window, text="Add", command=add_data)
button_add.pack()

def calculate_distances(vertices):
    distances = {}
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(vertices)):
            distance = ((vertices[i][1] - vertices[j][1]) ** 2 + (vertices[i][2] - vertices[j][2]) ** 2) ** 0.5
            distances[(vertices[i][0], vertices[j][0])] = distance
            distances[(vertices[j][0], vertices[i][0])] = distance
            # table.set(f"{i+1}", "distance", str(distance))
            # table.set(f"{j+1}", "distance", str(distance))
    return distances


def build_graph():
    # getting data from the table
    vertices = []
    for child in table.get_children():
        values = table.item(child)['values']
        vertices.append((values[0], float(values[1]), float(values[2])))

    # calculating distances
    distances = calculate_distances(vertices)

    # making graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    for vertex in vertices:
        G.add_node(vertex[0])
    for edge, distance in distances.items():
        G.add_edge(edge[0], edge[1], weight=round(distance, 2))

    # graph visualization 
    pos = {}
    for vertex in vertices:
        pos[vertex[0]] = (vertex[1], vertex[2])
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, node_size=700, node_color='lightblue', font_weight='bold', font_size=10,
            edge_color='grey', width=2, edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
    labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=labels)
    plt.show()


window = tk.Tk()
# creating table
create_table()

build_graph_button = tk.Button(window, text="Построить граф", command=build_graph)
build_graph_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

As you can see in the code I tried filling distance column with numbers and then replace it with distance value using table.set, however I kept getting this error: Item 1 is not found.
Any ideas how to fix this and insert the minimal distance for each vertex into table?

Comment: The first argument of `.set()` is the item ID returned by `.insert()`.

Comment: so how do I set an id for each value in distance column before replacing it with actual calculated distance ?

Comment: You can set the *item ID* for each row using `iid` option when calling `table.insert(...)`. If `iid` is not given, it will be generated implicitly. As I said in past comment, it is returned by `table.insert(...)`.